# URL regex in django for GET request

Tags: regex, django, url, django-views

I have a django URL

```
      url(r'^my/url/(?P<number>[0-9]{10})/$',My.as_view()),
```

and the request URL is

```
      my/url/?number=9876543210
```

The view is a JSONResponseView

```
class My(JSONResponseView):

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super(SendMobileLinkResponse,self).__init__(self,**kwargs)

    def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.render_to_response({"test": "uu"})
```

I am getting a 404 for the the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Rexford says in their answer, with Django you would normally avoid using get parameters in your url, and use something like `/my/url/9876543210/` instead.

If you do want to use GET parameters, don't include them in your url pattern.

```
url(r'^my/url/$',My.as_view()),
```

You can access the GET parameters in the view:

```
def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    number = self.request.GET.get('number', '') # default to ' '
    return self.render_to_response({"number": number})
```

Answer (score 2):

Please try this:

```
my/url/9876543210
```

Django believes in (of which I've also come to believe in) clean URLs. So your regex is catching

```
my/url/9876543210
```

instead of

```
my/url/?numbers=9876543210
```

Comment: SO how to make ajax request to this URL?